# MongoDB $all/$elemMatch woes

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if anyone else have run into this problem in MongoDB.

I'm trying to search an array inside another array with `$elemMatch` and then see if a nested value inside of this document, is in an array of values I provide.

Below there is a simple example:

```
db.p.insert({v: [{o: [{s: {e: ["M"] }} ]} ]});
db.p.findOne({"v.o": {"$all": [{"$elemMatch": {"s.e": {"$in": ["M"]}}}]}});
null
```

Note, the reason for the `$all` statement is that I want to be able to match several different fields, where each field doesn't necessarily exist on the documents in the array.

Answer (score 0):

[`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) is used to match an array property against a list of discrete values, not a list of conditions with operators like `$elemMatch`.  If you remove the `$all` it works:

```
db.p.findOne({"v.o": { $elemMatch: { "s.e": {"$in": ["M"]}}}});
```

Comment: According to: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824341/multiple-elemmatch-expressions-for-matching-array-values-using-all-in-mongodb) it does support matching using $elemMatch..

Comment: Interesting...undocumented feature!