# update the mongodb embedded document with $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model with array of embedded documents.

```
var CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
         invitations: [InvitationSchema],
         total:Number
});

var InvitationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    token: { type:String, required: true},
    email: String
});
```

want to update/increase the total number of invitation by matching the token of invitation embedded array from the request, here I followed a tutorial in http://diogogmt.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/update-elementmatch-and-the-positional-operator-on-mongodbmongoose/

so I tried

```
var options = { new: false , select:'_id'};
CourseModel.update({'_id':id,'invitations':{'$elemMatch':{'token':token}}},{'$inc':{'total':1}},options,function(err,data) { 
    if(err){callback(err, null);}
    else{
        callback(null, data);
    }      
})
```

But it doesn't work,  if I remove the 'invitations':{'$elemMatch':{'token':token}}, the query would work

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it.  What doesn't work about what you're trying?

Comment: I tried on mongo shell, works as well. I guess the mongoose doesn't work for some reason. I am checking what is the problem now

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) $elemMatch can be used for projection only. But i found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824341/multiple-elemmatch-expressions-for-matching-array-values-using-all-in-mongodb) which illustrate the use of $elemMatch in conjunction with $all. Try this out.

1) I created a document in collection in the following ways:

```
db.testColl.insert({count:0,arr:[{token:'xya'},{token:'xyb'},{token:'xyc'},{token:'xyd'},{token:'xye'}]})
```

2) then i use find command without

```
db.testColl.find()
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52345478ef5f122b1c9c54be"), "count" : 0, "arr" : [  {   "token" : "xya" },  {   "token" : "xyb" },  {   "token" : "xyc" },  {   "token" : "xyd" },  {   "token" : "xye" } ] }
```

3) then i run the following command sequentially:

```
db.testColl.update({arr:{$elemMatch:{token:'xya'}}},{'$inc':{'count':1}})
db.testColl.update({arr:{$elemMatch:{token:'xyb'}}},{'$inc':{'count':1}})
db.testColl.update({arr:{$elemMatch:{token:'xyc'}}},{'$inc':{'count':1}})
db.testColl.update({arr:{$elemMatch:{token:'xyd'}}},{'$inc':{'count':1}})
db.testColl.update({arr:{$elemMatch:{token:'xye'}}},{'$inc':{'count':1}})
```

4) Now, db.testColl.find() gives me the right output which is required:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52345478ef5f122b1c9c54be"), "count" : 5, "arr" : [  {   "token" : "xya" },  {   "token" : "xyb" },  {   "token" : "xyc" },  {   "token" : "xyd" },  {   "token" : "xye" } ] }
```

So, your query seems to be fine!!!

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch  if you see this, $elementMatch can be also used for query

Comment: Yes, you are right that can be used for querying as well. But, it return the whole document if it match any of the token in the array invitations? It is the same you wanted? can you please mention any example what should be the output in the question itself?

Comment: there are two elements in the InvitationSchema ,which are token and email, so in course there should be many invitations sent out, when a client accepts the invitation, the token is provided to the web, the database will check whether this token is in the invitation list. if it is in one of the list, it will increase the total number of accepted client - that is 'total' element in the CourseSchema. All I want is just to update the document if the match is satisfied, not returned document is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Anuj. I have also used the mongo shell to test it. The query works, however it is strange the mongoose doesn't work on it. maybe it is due to the wrong version of mongoose, I have to check it out now

Comment: Thanks @user824624, for confirming. Yes, might be a version issue. Btw, i have checked this on mongo 2.4.6.

Comment: As a note, `$elemMatch` works correctly with updates in at least 2.6 and 3.0.  A la: `db.foo.update({arr: {$elemMatch: {a: "b"}}}, {$inc: {"arr.$.t": 1}})`