# MongoDB C# Driver - $match with the same field twice

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a collection of survey response documents that look like this:

```
{
    _id: ...  
    surveryId: ...  
    created: ...  
    answers:  [ 
    {
        "k" : "53ac9a031703670858aff600",
        "v" : "Yes"
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec",
        "v" : "75731431"
    },
    ...
    {
        "k" : "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ee",
        "v" : "71825"
    }
}
```

How would I create aggregation match operator where "53ac9a031703670858aff600" equals "Yes" and "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec" equals "75731431" **using the C# driver**?

I can run the following query in mongo shell and get the results I am looking for:

```
db.Records.aggregate([{ "$match" : { 
    "answers" : { "$elemMatch" : { "k" : "53ac9a031703670858aff600", "v" : "Yes" } }, 
    "answers" : { "$elemMatch" : { "k" : "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec", "v" : "75731431" } } 
}}])
```

I try to express the same query in C# but get an error because of the duplicate answer key:

```
new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument
            {
                  { "answers", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "k", "53ac9a031703670858aff600" },
                                    { "v", "Yes" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                  },
                  { "answers", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "k", "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec" },
                                    { "v", "75731431" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                  }
            }
```

I have tried using a single answers element with a BsonArray of $elemMatch elements, but the resulting JSON does not return any results.

How can I express the above $match operator using the C# driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a look at [Multiple $elemMatch expressions for matching array values using $all in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824341/multiple-elemmatch-expressions-for-matching-array-values-using-all-in-mongodb) there should be one "answers" element and a $all to wrap each $elemMatch.  So the correct $match operator should be:

```
db.Records.aggregate([{ "$match" : { 
    "answers" : { "$all": [ 
        {"$elemMatch" : { "k" : "53ac9a031703670858aff600", "v" : "Yes" } }, 
        { "$elemMatch" : { "k" : "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec", "v" : "75731431" } } 
    ]}
}}])
```

Which makes the C# code look like this:

```
new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument
            {
                  { "answers", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "$all", new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument("$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            { "k", "53ac9a031703670858aff600" },
                                            { "v", "Yes" }
                                        }),
                                    new BsonDocument("$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "k", "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec" },
                                        { "v", "75731431" }
                                    })
                                }

                            }
                        }
                   }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var query = Query.And(
   Query.EQ("Field1", "somevalue"),
   Query.EQ("Field2", "somevalue")
 );
```

or

```
var query = from e in collection.AsQueryable<Person>()
                            where e.Field1 == "someval" &&
                            e.Field2 == "someotherVal"
select e;
```

You could then loop further if need be

```
foreach (var thing in query)
 {
   ///  access thing        
 }
```

or use cursor

```
        var cursor = collection.FindAs<BsonDocument>(Query.EQ("field1", "value"));
        cursor.SetFields(Fields.Include("otherfield"));
        var items = cursor.ToList();
```

there's other ways but that all for today....

Comment: I need to be able to use a $match operator so that I can use the results of the $match in other steps in the aggregation pipeline.  Also your code above is not using elemMatch, will it only return results that match both fields in the same sub document?

Comment: last one is document, as in from a collection, middle one is collection but mapped to c# objects using linq, first one would return a collection, you could easily narrow it down using 2 then loop further, sorry dont know much about $match, but linq is the way to go IMHO, see this thread about aggregation and linq https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-383 and a tutorial http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c-

Comment: As noted in the referenced MongoDB JIRA ticket, LINQ support for aggregations will not be available until the 2.0 version of the C# driver which as of this writing has not yet been released.