# Mongodb Array ElemMatch with 2 conditions

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection "foo":

```
db.foo.insert({a:[1, 10]})
db.foo.insert({a:[4, 6]})
```

and a query:

```
db.foo.find({a: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 5, $lte: 7}}})
```

and result is:

```
{a: [4, 6]}
```

My question is how to use `Query.ElemMatch()` in this situation?

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266994/how-can-i-and-multiple-elemmatch-clauses-with-c-sharp-and-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

You can use C#'s collection initializer syntax to clean it up a bit:

```
Query.ElemMatch("a", new QueryDocument {
    {"$gte", 5}, 
    {"$lte", 7}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem and hope it's useful for someone

```
Query.ElemMatch("a", Query.And(new QueryDocument("$gte", 5), new QueryDocument("$lte", 7)))
```