# Query deeply embeded documents in MongoDB with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is just an example code... I have managed to get to the third embeded document using `.$` , but not further... How do I query the fourth nested part(article headings)?

```
  {
    "bookTitle": "MongoDB",
    "_id": ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b60"),
    "bookChapters": [{
    "chapterTitle": "chapterTitle",
    "_id": ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b61"),
    "chapterArticles": [{
        "articleTitle": "articleTitle",
        "_id": ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b62"),
        "articleHeadings": [{
            "headingTitle": "headingTitle",
            "_id": ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b63")
        }]
    }]
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match nested element in array. I used `headingTitle` to match here. Query will be like following-

```
db.collection.find({
    "bookChapters": {
    "$elemMatch": {
        "chapterArticles": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "articleHeadings": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "headingTitle": "headingTitle"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
})
```

If you want to convert it to `mongo c#` driver then you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266994/how-can-i-and-multiple-elemmatch-clauses-with-c-sharp-and-mongodb)