# Execute mongodb shell script via C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6120629/526799) question and haven't understand. Is there ability to execute arbitrary mongodb shell script via C# driver?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var mongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://<connectionstring>"); 
var database = mongoServer.GetDatabase("mydatabase"); 
string mycollectionCount database.Eval("function() { return db.mycollection.count(); }").ToString();
```

This is useful when you are trying to change property types for example like this:

```
string updateScript = @"
function () { 
    db.some_items.find().forEach(function(documentItem) {
        documentItem.some_collection.forEach(function(collectionItem) {
            if (typeof collectionItem.SomeProperty === 'number' 
                && Math.floor(collectionItem.someProperty) === collectionItem.someProperty)
            {
                collectionItem.someProperty = '' + collectionItem.someProperty;
            }
        });
        db.modules_elementary.save(documentItem);
    });

    return true;
}";
var updateResult = MongoReadDatabase.Database.Eval(updateScript).ToString();
if (updateResult != "true")
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Update of something failed");
}
```

This code changes type of `someProperty` which is element of a collection of a collection:

```
some_items mongo collection:

{
   some_collection: [{ someProperty: 12, ....}],
   ....

}
```

Comment: May I please know if there is a way for the invoked javascript to return complex types ( which would ultimately be POCOs in the C# code ) back to the C# module?

Comment: @CSLewis If I'm not mistaken mongodb .net driver for `Database.Eval()` method returns `BsonValue` - the result of script execution on server. You can try to cast it to some `BsonDocument`, taking into consideration, that script execution could be failed by server and instead some Data in `BsonValue` you will have error message in the `Eval()`'s result. Anyways, this all code is a hack. If you are using this code in a normal app execution flow, you are definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Thx. Could you please take a quick glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456071/c-sharp-world-has-problems-retrieving-valid-data-from-javascript-function-that-i  ?

Answer (score 4):

No, you'd need launch a Mongo shell process, using something like [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), and pass in the command you want to execute, e.g.

```
mongo.exe mydb --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
```

However, the [C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial) can do most things the shell can, so if possible it's much easier to use the driver directly.

Comment: I haven't tested you proposal to run mongo admin util using `Process.Start` and passing it command to execute. But it seems that it should work. It's a pity, that I cannot manage only with C# driver here. Using mongo admint util and `Process.Start` looks a bit clumsy. If nobody adds any new idea how to use only C# driver to run arbitrary mongo shell script in nearest time, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Caution: even though it is a working solution, it is very wrong in terms of security, portability and robustness.

Comment: Are you saying that it isn't possible to execute arbitrary queries for update/retrieval at all? I'm very much in favor of C#, lambda expressions etc. but when it come to MongoDb, a lot of help comes in form of script (also trying out different things in a client produces script too). When I convert that to C#'ish code, I end up with a gazillion of `new BsonDocument(...)` nested into each other beyond the point of decency and sanity.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried it but I think this is what you are looking for:

**MongoServer.RunAdminCommand Method (String)**
http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/a83249ae-0989-7c24-7240-4506053d83c1.htm

Comment: `server.RunAdminCommand(@"db.blog.insert({title: ""My Blog Post""});");` gives error `Command 'db.blog.insert({title: "My Blog Post"});' failed: no such cmd: db.blog.insert({title: "My Blog Post"}); (response: { "errmsg" : "no such cmd: db.blog.insert({title: \"My Blog Post\"});", "bad cmd" : { "db.blog.insert({title: \"My Blog Post\"});" : true }, "ok" : 0 })`

Comment: Seems that arbitrary script couldn't be executed using `MongoServer.RunAdminCommand()` method.

Comment: @Dao + by the MogoDB User => can lead to permission escalation