# Rename field of complex type that is located in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm doing refactoring on production database and need to make some renamings. Version of mongodb is 1.8.0. I use C# driver to do refactoring of database. Have faced with problem when I try to rename field of complex type that is located in array.

For example I have such document:

```
FoobarCollection:

{
  Field1: "",
  Field2: [
    { NestedField1: "", NestedField2: "" },
    { NestedField1: "", NestedField2: "" },
    ... 
  ]
}
```

I Need to rename `NestedField2` into `NestedField3`, for example.
MongoDB documentation says:

> $rename
>
> Version 1.7.2+ only.
>
> { $rename : { old_field_name : new_field_name } }
>   Renames the field with name 'old_field_name' to 'new_field_name'. **Does not expand arrays to find a match for 'old_field_name'**.

As I understand, simply using `Update.Rename()` wouldn't give result, because as documentation says "rename - doesn't expand arrays to find a match for old field name"

What C# code I should write to rename `NestedField2` into `NestedField3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented special type to do renaming of arbitrary field in MongoDB. Here is it:

```
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DatabaseManagementTools
{
    public class MongoDbRefactorer
    {
        protected MongoDatabase MongoDatabase { get; set; }

        public MongoDbRefactorer(MongoDatabase mongoDatabase)
        {
            MongoDatabase = mongoDatabase;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Renames field
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collectionName"></param>
        /// <param name="oldFieldNamePath">Supports nested types, even in array. Separate nest level with '$': "FooField1$FooFieldNested$FooFieldNestedNested"</param>
        /// <param name="newFieldName">Specify only field name without path to it: "NewFieldName", but not "FooField1$NewFieldName"</param>
        public void RenameField(string collectionName, string oldFieldNamePath, string newFieldName)
        {
            MongoCollection<BsonDocument> mongoCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection(collectionName);
            MongoCursor<BsonDocument> collectionCursor = mongoCollection.FindAll();

            PathSegments pathSegments = new PathSegments(oldFieldNamePath);

            // Rename field in each document of collection
            foreach (BsonDocument document in collectionCursor)
            {
                int currentSegmentIndex = 0;
                RenameField(document, pathSegments, currentSegmentIndex, newFieldName);

                // Now document is modified in memory - replace old document with new in mongo:
                mongoCollection.Save(document);
            }
        }

        private void RenameField(BsonValue bsonValue, PathSegments pathSegments, int currentSegmentIndex, string newFieldName)
        {
            string currentSegmentName = pathSegments[currentSegmentIndex];

            if (bsonValue.IsBsonArray)
            {
                var array = bsonValue.AsBsonArray;
                foreach (var arrayElement in array)
                {
                    RenameField(arrayElement.AsBsonDocument, pathSegments, currentSegmentIndex, newFieldName);
                }
                return;
            }

            bool isLastNameSegment = pathSegments.Count() == currentSegmentIndex + 1;
            if (isLastNameSegment)
            {
                RenameDirect(bsonValue, currentSegmentName, newFieldName);
                return;
            }

            var innerDocument = bsonValue.AsBsonDocument[currentSegmentName];
            RenameField(innerDocument, pathSegments, currentSegmentIndex + 1, newFieldName);
        }

        private void RenameDirect(BsonValue document, string from, string to)
        {
            BsonElement bsonValue;
            bool elementFound = document.AsBsonDocument.TryGetElement(from, out bsonValue);
            if (elementFound)
            {
                document.AsBsonDocument.Add(to, bsonValue.Value);
                document.AsBsonDocument.Remove(from);
            }
            else
            {
                // todo: log missing elements
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And helper type to keep path segments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DatabaseManagementTools
{
    public class PathSegments : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        private List<string> Segments { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Split segment levels with '$'. For example: "School$CustomCodes"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathToParse"></param>
        public PathSegments(string pathToParse)
        {
            Segments = ParseSegments(pathToParse);
        }

        private static List<string> ParseSegments(string oldFieldNamePath)
        {
            string[] pathSegments = oldFieldNamePath.Trim(new []{'$', ' '})
                .Split(new [] {'$'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            return pathSegments.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Segments.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public string this[int index]
        {
            get { return Segments[index]; }
        }
    }
}
```

To separate nest levels I use '$' sign - the only sign that is forbidden for collection names in mongo.
Usage can be something like this:

```
MongoDbRefactorer mongoDbRefactorer = new MongoDbRefactorer(Mongo.Database);
mongoDbRefactorer.RenameField("schools", "FoobarTypesCustom$FoobarDefaultName", "FoobarName");
```

This code will find in collection `schools` `FoobarTypesCustom` property. It can be as complex type so array. Then will find all `FoobarDefaultName` properties (if `FoobarTypesCustom` is array then it will iterate through it) and rename it to `FoobarName`. Nesting levels and number of nested arrays no matters.

Comment: Hello This is exactly i was looking for ! Thank you ! Do you have code to update the data type too ?

Comment: I have no general solution for now. But have concrete example. I do it using javascript execution. Because, as I think, it is impossible to do this using only clear C# and mondodb C# driver. You can look for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11726630/459485).

Comment: This was a life saver, although I had a sparse collection, so I needed to add a check for if (document == BsonNull.Value) { return; } at the top of RenameDirect to get it to work properly.