# C# world has problems retrieving valid data from javaScript function that is gets data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, complextype

Here is the information about my development environment:

- MongoDB 3.0.0
- MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
- .NET Framework 4.0

We have code that uses C# MongoDB Driver API to invoke a JavaScript file that will query the MongoDB database.

Here is the excerpt of the said C# code:

```
var sysJs = DBConnection.database.GetCollection("system.js");

sysJs.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", "getArray"));
var code = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/folderPathtoJSFile/getArray.js"));

var codeDocument = new BsonDocument("value", new BsonJavaScript(code));
codeDocument.Add(new BsonElement("_id", "getArray"));

sysJs.Insert(codeDocument);

BsonValue bv = DBConnection.database.Eval("getArray");

BsonValue bv1 = DBConnection.database.Eval(bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, blahIdArg, BlahStatusArg);
```

Here is the contents of the getArray.js JavaScript file:

```
function (blahIdArg, BlahStatusArg) {

    var someJavaScriptObjectMap = {};
    someJavaScriptObjectMap["firstEntry"] = "JohnDoe";
    someJavaScriptObjectMap["secondEntry"] = "JaneDoe";

    return someJavaScriptObjectMap;
}
```

When I try to retrieve the returned JavaScript data by placing it in bv1, I saw the following using the Visual Studio Add Watch feature:

```
bv1 {}
```

Could someone please explain how I can retrieve the properly values in the C# world?

Comment: did you get any progress on that?

Comment: I programmed my JavaScript in a different way that involves returning an array of documents belonging to a MongoDB collection,
and then I used the BsonSerializer to Deserialize the JSON (Please click on the link here ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554495/error-thrown-when-trying-to-convert-from-mongodb-bsonarray-to-ienumerableusers