# Reading a query from file and executing it

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using Mongo 3.4.4 and the latest version of the C# driver. 
What I want to be able to do is read a query from a file and have it executed against a Mongo database. 
I know I can use the Linq bits in the driver to do this but our customer has a large library of queries already written (and tested) using the Mongo shell and they want to be able to use those queries as is.

Some (most) of the queries are pretty straight-forward:

```
db.registers.find({ "Permissions" : "WEEE" }).sort({ "Name" : 1 }).skip(0).limit(20)

db.restaurants.aggregate([{"$match": {"name": "Bob Smith"}}, {"$skip": 0}, {"$limit": 10}, {"$sort" :{"name" : 1}}])
```

I was hoping it would be able to parse those queries and pass them off to database.RunCommand but I have not been able to make any progress.

```
var bsonDoc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("<some query that was read from a file>");
database.RunCommand(command);
```

That code fails on the call to Deserialize with this error message: [Additional information: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.] which makes perfect sense because the script is not valid JSON.

So I'm having trouble parsing the script into something that can be executed.

Before spending too much more time on this I am hoping that someone can tell me whether this is possible or not.

Comment: do you want to execute these commands from c# code itself? You can also put these queries in .js file and have them execute using mongo x.js from command line

Comment: i want them to execute from c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002975/execute-mongodb-shell-script-via-c-sharp-driver may be useful. Not sure if it will actually answer your question but seems a good starting point at least.

Comment: I did look at that question earlier today. That Eval method is not available using the lastest version of the C# driver. Having to call Process.Start on a new mongo instance seems a bit clunky but it might be the only option I have