# How do I query MongoDB using the C# driver with a query in string format?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to query MongoDB with a standard query like the following:

```
{"$and":[{"Name":"Accelero JKT M Tun XL "}]}
```

I typically build queries using the Query object in C# and then do something like this:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> col = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SourceItem");
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("AccountID", BsonValue.Create(Convert.ToInt32(_accountID))), Query.EQ("SKU", sku));
var docs = col.Find(query);
```

Since I already have the query, I do not want to use the Query object to build a query. How do I simply use the query that I already have?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120629/can-i-do-a-text-query-with-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slightly simpler way to do this (you should just replace `"` with `'`):

```
var el = BsonDocument.Parse("{'$and':[{'Name':'Accelero JKT M Tun XL '}]}");
var doc = new QueryDocument(el);
var result = coll.Find(doc);
```